# How to listen to specific IP address

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, ip, listener

On my server, under advanced TCP/IP settings I have two IP addresses added. 
My question is, how can I specify that I want to listen to the first or second IP? Is there a way to obtain all IP addresses on my machine via .NET and select one to listen to?

Any help would be appreciated. I hope my question is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: Listen to it *where*? In your application? Across the entire machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TCPListener` in `System.Net.Sockets` accepts an IP and a port on construction:

```
  Int32 port = 13000;
  IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

  // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
  server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
```

The full MSDN article is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and also look at the [TCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) queried with an empty string returns the local host adresses. You then can bind your server socket on a specific address (see [Socket.Bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) and [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll give this a try tonight. It'll definitely help to get list of local host addresses. Though I would like to ask, are there two local IP's if I have two IP's assigned on my machine? (May sound like a stupid question) :-)

Comment: What are you calling a "local IP"? 127.0.0.1?